# Qt Creator doesn't start

Tags: qt-creator, archlinux

I have been using Qt Creator for some time now without a problem. Now i try to start it and it just doesn't. It looks like it's loading and then it crashes.

I have tried to fix it by reinstalling it several times, i deleted all the config files, just in case, nothing.

I'm on Arch Linux and here is the error it throws when i launch it from the terminal:

```
/usr/bin/qtcreator: line 2:  4379 Bus error               (core dumped) QT_LOGGING_TO_CONSOLE=1 qtcreator-bin $@
```

Comment: What version of qtcreator are you using? Is this the whole error message? If not, then please paste whole error. What is your architecture?

Comment: version 3.5.1 that is the whole message and i'm running 64bit. when i launch qtcreator with an argument, like -version, which doesn't have to open a window, it doesn't crash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run qtcreator in gdb to find out where (in which library) it crashes. Try to reinstall that library.

Or: I assume you installed qtcreator via your distribution packages. QT offers binary packages for qtcreator, which you can try.

Comment: gdb says that it's not an executable. (I checked of course and the permissions are fine). i installed it, as you said from the binaries and it works. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

Got similar. Debugging into showed that systemd service cannot open journal files properly (memory mapped it is, thats why SIGBUS).
You can test with issuing command and seeing output like below:

```
journalctl --disk-usage
```

> An error was encountered while opening journal file or directory /var/log/journal/606980f452a14d4bb7327a74a7ff41ee/system@00057ba473706a85-48f3052664924467.journal~,
>   ignoring file: Input/output error Archived and active journals take up
>   171.0M in the file system.

To fix that you must do full disk check (on start, press E in grab and add kernel parameter fsck.mode=force).
Then delete all journals and restart service (well, you will lose some old messages, add path where you journals are according to prev ouput):

```
sudo rm -rf /var/log/journal 
sudo systemctl kill --kill-who=main --signal=SIGUSR2 systemd journald.service
```

Problem will go away itself in couple days maybe, if systemd will do rotation and delete old journals. Any way, in my case it was caused by power loss.